# Flagging bug in mobile site

Tags: bug

When I flag a post on SO on the mobile version of the site, there's a bug with the flag popup paging that renders it partially unusable.

The initial page displays just fine:

[image]

But upon selecting "it is a duplicate..." and (then) "off-topic because...", the textbox to answer the question appears on top of the flag window, rendering certain flag types unselectable:

[image] [image]

The "it is a duplicate..." option gets even funkier:

[image]

This is reproducible on my iPhone 4/iOS 7.1.1 in both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I have the exact same issues on wp7.8

Comment: This has been a bug for a while now, but seems to have been fixed lately. Running Android 4.4.2 using chrome and aosp browser without issue atm.

Comment: Using the "request desktop site" button in chrome does resolve the issue but then of course we're no longer actually dealing with the mobile version of the site. I can still reproduce the bug.